# Error when storing the first line of a file to a variable

Tags: bash

I am doing basic programs with Linux shell scripting(bash)

I want to read the first line of a file and store it in a variable .

My input file :

```
100|Surender|CHN
101|Raja|BNG
102|Kumar|CHN
```

My shell script is below

```
first_line=cat /home/user/inputfiles/records.txt | head -1
echo $first_line
```

I am executing the shell script with bash records.sh

It throws me error as

```
 /home/user/inputfiles/records.txt line 1: command not found
```

Could some one help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
first_line=cat /home/user/inputfiles/records.txt | head -1
```

sets variable `first_line` to `cat` and then tries to execute the rest as a command resulting in an error.

You should use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) to execute `cat .../records.txt | head -1` as a command:

```
first_line=`cat /home/user/inputfiles/records.txt | head -1`
echo $first_line
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried as Per your suggestion and it worked .  Could you also tell me when do I need to go and apply backticks while writing shell script

Comment: You need to use backticks (command substitution) whenever you want to use the output of some command to replace the command itself.

Comment: Ok fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The other answer addresses the obvious mistake you made. Though, you're not using the idiomatic way of reading the first line of a file. Please consider this instead (more efficient, avoiding a subshell, a pipe, two external processes among which a useless use of `cat`):

```
IFS= read -r first_line < /home/user/inputfiles/records.txt
```